# how highlight bar button item? (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i use toolbar items for using action properties, i want when i tapped on on of the items, images be change to highlighted image.

this is my all three buttons :

```
@IBAction func audio(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.scView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
}

@IBAction func mainBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.scView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(415,0);
}

@IBAction func videoBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.scView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(830,0);
}

@IBOutlet var inpt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var scView: UIScrollView!
```

this is my app picture:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DExyF.png)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to show the button with a highlighted images while you are pressing the button - you can do that through the storyboard - you can set the image for each button in the `default` state and also in `highlighted` - but when you release the button, it goes back to the original image.

If you want the image to toggle when you select the button, you're going to have to add outlets for the buttons, and a button state variable (if it only changes once, and never goes back to the original, then you don't need the state)

Here's an example of how you might do it - updated to reset the 'other' button

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var videoButton: UIButton!

var mainButtonSelected : Bool = false
var videoButtonSelected : Bool = false

@IBAction func mainButton(sender: AnyObject)
{
    mainButtonSelected = !mainButtonSelected // toggle state
    if mainButtonSelected
    {
        // highlight the mainButton
        mainButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageMainHighlight.png"), forState: .Normal)

        // clear the highlight (if any) on videoButton
        videoButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageVideoDefault.png"), forState: .Normal)

        // UPDATED
        // make sure the videoButtonSelected flag is correct
        videoButtonSelected = false
        // UPDATED
    }
    else
    {
        // clear the highlight on mainButton, no need to do anything with videoButton
        mainButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageMainDefault.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }

    // add any other code you need here
}

@IBAction func videoButton(sender: AnyObject)
{
    videoButtonSelected = !videoButtonSelected // toggle state
    if videoButtonSelected
    {
        // highlight videoButton
        videoButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageVideoHighlight.png"), forState: .Normal)
        // clear the highlight (if any) on mainButton
        mainButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageMainDefault.png"), forState: .Normal)

        // UPDATED
        // make sure the mainButtonSelected flag is correct
        mainButtonSelected = false
        // UPDATED
    }
    else
    {
        // clear the highlight on videoButton, no need to do anything for mainButton
        videoButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageVideoDefault.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }

    // add any other code you need here
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but setImages dosen't work in my code,

Comment: i use 'mainButton.image = UIImage(named: "eye.png")' , its work but i want if i tapped another tabbar item, the previous tab item be untapped, can you handle it?:)

Comment: so you want the buttons to act like toggles?  if you click on `mainButton`, we show the highlighted image, and clear the highlight (if any) from `videoButton` - and the same the other way around?

Comment: Assuming that's what you need - I have updated the answer with one approach you could use

Comment: thank you a lot, i have a problem, for the first time your code work fine but for second try, i should taped a button twise for highlighted a button.

Comment: good catch - the code was resetting the image, but not the flag, if the 'other' button was already highlighted and you select the other.  I have updated the code in the answer above.

Comment: you know, you are awesome:))